# Search part of phone number with Sunspot Solr

Tags: solr, sunspot, solr4, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am developing rails app with sunspot Solr search engine and I'm in need of indexing phone numbers in Solr 4.1.

For example, if I have phone number "+12 (456) 789-0101", my page should be founded by queries:

- +12 (456) 789-0101  (phone in correct format)
- +12 (456) 789.........  (left part of phone in correct format)
- .......(456) 789-0101  (right part of phone in correct format)
- .......(456) 789.........  (middle part of phone in correct format)
- 124567890101        (full phone with numbers only)
- 1245678..........        (left part of phone with catenated numbers)
- ............890101        (right part of phone with catenated numbers)
- ......567890......        (middle part of phone with catenated numbers)

I know that I can use:

- `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` for splitting phone to NGrams (front and back)
- `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` for catenate numbers and splitting phone for parts.

So, what I have done:

1. Create new Solr field type in `shema.xml`:

   `<fieldType name="phone_number" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="20" side="front"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="20" side="back"/>
      </analyzer>
   </fieldType>`

   `<dynamicField name="*_phone"  stored="false" type="phone_number" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>`
2. Define searchable phone fields as '*_phone' type:

   `string :work_phone, :as => :work_phone, :stored => true do
       work_phone.gsub(/\D/, '') if work_phone
     end`

   `string :mobile_phone, :as => :mobile_phone, :stored => true do
       mobile_phone.gsub(/\D/, '') if mobile_phone
     end`
3. Run reindexing:

   `bundle exec rake sunspot:rebuild`

   But it does not work when reindexing finished, I can found results only searching wiht queries: "full phone" and "left part of phone". Search with "middle part of phone" and "right part of phone" doesn't give me any results.

Did I make somethig wrong? How to make phone part searing correctly?
Please, help. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ectualy, it is my code, which works:

Schema.xml:

```
    <fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="phone_number" positionIncrementGap="100">       
    <analyzer type="index">         
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>         
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>         
      <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="20"/>
    </analyzer>       
    <analyzer type="query">         
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>         
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>         
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1"/>       
    </analyzer>     
    </fieldType>

 <dynamicField name="*_phone"  stored="false"  type="phone_number" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
 <dynamicField name="*_phones" stored="false"  type="phone_number" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
```

And ruby code:

```
  text :work_phone

  text :work_phone_parts, :as => :work_phone do
    "00#{work_phone.gsub(/\D/, '')}" if work_phone
  end

  text :mobile_phone

  text :mobile_phone_parts, :as => :mobile_phone do
    "00#{mobile_phone.gsub(/\D/, '')}" if mobile_phone
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

(commenting on Solr part only, not sure how SunSpot can map it)

There is a couple of things not quite right here:

1. *side=back* is no longer an option since Solr 4.4, so you are probably just getting two copies of the same filter
2. Having two copies of the same filter is bad anyway, as the second one will look at all the tokens issued by the first and things will get messy.

Here is a good way to match suffixes, taking into account stripping all the random non-digit stuff and asymmetry of index/query (from my [AirPair Solr tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/solr/workshops/discovering-your-inner-search-engine)):

```
<fieldType name="phone" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^0-9])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="30"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^0-9])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Note that this will not help with queries that include spaces in them with default analyzer, as they will be broken up on space *before* they hit field analysis. If you know you are searching the phone number, you can either quote the search string or switch to a different ([probably field](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-FieldQueryParser)) query parser.

If you do want to match the middle, maybe you don't want any of that and just want NGram, not EdgeNGram analysis.

Comment: Thanks! so as I understood, I need to use NgramFilterFactory and PatternReplaceFilterFactory only to get expected results. do I need to remove spaces and other non-number symbols from query?

Comment: Can you kindly give me examle with Ngram factory to search using as query: phone in correct format, phone with numbers only and left/middle/right parts ( with and without space, "-", "+"). Thanks kindly!

Comment: I don't have one. But I think you should try replacing the Edge filter with normal one and seeing if that will do the trick. Worst case, you can *copyField* to another field and search both.